# Pasting columns of multiple files together line by line by iterating

Tags: rust, iterator, concatenation, paste

I want to concatenate an unknown number of files side by side, but I'm making a bit of a mess. The operation would be roughly similar to unix `paste`. I thought I could iterate line by line over every file and write every element from every file to stdout, but it is proving harder than expected. Maybe there is a far better approach?

Every file looks like

```
name1 value1
name2 value2
name3 value3
name4 value4
```

I want to treat the first file special, because each row has an identifier (name as in the example above). The files are known to be sorted and of the same length, so I don't have to check anything while pasting the files together. For every file after the first file I don't have to write the name field again, and I can just take the value field. I haven't even started to bother with splitting those columns because I'm stuck iterating over all files simultaneously.

The code below doesn't compile, since

```
use of moved value: `iterfiles`rustcE0382
combine.rs(17, 14): `iterfiles` moved due to this method call, in previous iteration of loop
```

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::path::PathBuf;

pub fn combine(calls: Vec<PathBuf>) {
    let file1 = File::open(calls[0].clone()).unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(file1).lines();
    let mut files = Vec::new();
    for file in &calls[1..] {
        files.push(BufReader::new(File::open(file).unwrap()).lines());
    }
    let iterfiles = files.iter();
    for line in reader {
        let mut line_out = Vec::new();
        line_out.push(line.unwrap());
        let rest_of_files: Vec<String> = iterfiles
            .map(|file2| file2.next().unwrap().unwrap())
            .collect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move it into the loop body and then use `iter_mut` instead of `iter`:

```
for line in reader {
    let mut line_out = Vec::new();
    line_out.push(line.unwrap());
    let rest_of_files: Vec<String> = files.iter_mut()
        .map(|file2| file2.next().unwrap().unwrap())
        .collect();
}
```

By the way, you can construct `files` like this:

```
let mut files: Vec<_> = calls[1..].iter()
    .map(|file| BufReader::new(File::open(file).unwrap()).lines())
    .collect();
```

And you don't need the `clone` for `file1`:

```
let file1 = File::open(&calls[0]).unwrap();
```

Comment: Aha that's great, thanks for your insight!